# How can I document optional parameters

Tags: c, parameters, doxygen

My function has a different parameter list depending on if a device feature is enabled via a `#define` constant `SMBSUS_INH`

e.g.

```
#ifndef SMBUS_INH
    handle initHandle(foo_t foo, SMB_Info_t smbInfo, bar_t bar);
#else
    handle initHandle(foo_t foo, bar_t bar);
#endif
```

How can I correctly document this?

If I write the documentation, twice, once inside each of the #if...else clauses will doxygen ignore the irrelevant one? Or will it still see bothe documentation blocks and complain that one has no related function?

Is there a better way of managing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen does some partial preprocessing : if you put specific documentation in the if/else part, only the relevant documentation will be shown. However, is it really a good thing ? As a user, I may be interested in seeing every different prototype, even though disabled at compile-time.

source : http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks! 
Well the idea is that the users would be reading the documentation, where the `#define` switch is also documented. I could just, for e.g., leave the parameters in and have the user set them NULL if not used, but the unused code would still need space and this is on an embedded platform so space is crucial. Using the switch means the code is only on the device if that feature is available.

Comment: Although I guess I could just use the switch internally to the function and comment out the relevant code portions...